# How to convert 8 characters String to ARGB color format in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, colors, floating-point

When I type in a color code (`AARRGGBB`) into a text field I need to update a component with the color represented by the string (which is formatted to `AARRGGBB`).  I divide it into 4 substrings and there I get to a halt.

I need to have the RR string to a float value so after all the process I should create a color like:

```
Color c = new Color(floatA, floatR, floatG, floatB);
```

Any suggestion is welcome as long as in the end I will have the color.

Comment: 1) ok 2)kinda 3) I already have a colorchooser associated with the textfield from where I take the color code. I am writing an actionListener and a focusListener for the textField which says that when I type the color code, a button will color accordingly and the parsed color will also be set to the colorChooser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Color((int)Long.parseLong(code, 16), true);
```

might work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FF1A0000"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)

Comment: The exception confused me a bit, but that could be because Java doesn't support unsigned integral types and thus `F0000000` is not allowed to parse as a negative number but instead would have to be `-10000000`.

Answer (score 1):

Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).

```
new Color(100, 100, 100, 10) ;
```

Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

```
new Color(0x000000, false); // BLACK 
new Color(0x00000000, true); // TRANSPARENT_BLACK
```